# where put clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml ? - 404 not found error

Tags: silverlight, http-status-code-404

I have Silverlight app and when I want to do some action Firebug show me that on this two files I have 404 not found error.

So should I insert this files somewhere in my solution or to IIS rootwww directory?

Or it's other solution of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put those files in the root virtual directory of IIS, which defaults to C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\, such that the file shows up as "`http://<yourdomain>/clientaccesspolicy.xml`", or "`http://<yourserver>/clientaccesspolicy.xml`".

Comment: should I have my application in root virtual directory to it works ok?

Comment: No, where your application resides should have no bearing on the placement of the clientaccesspolicy file.